# pgfplots ticks are not applied

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to create a 3D plot with custom z-ticks. However I can not create them with starting negative number. It works however as expected when the ticks start at 0.

My code is this one

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={30}{30},grid=major,
   /pgfplots/xtick={0,60,...,300},
   /pgfplots/ytick={0,60,...,300},
   /pgfplots/ztick={-1.0,0.2,...,1.0},
]
\addplot3[surf,domain=0:360,samples=40,
  colormap/jet,colorbar]
  {sin(x)*sin(y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with these results (the second with `ztick={0,0.2,...,1.0}`):
[image]

[image]

How do I get correct z-ticks from -1 to 1 with steps 0.2?

Comment: within the axis environment the extra `/pgfplots` should not be needed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The second number does not give the step size, but the next step. So try `{-1.0,-0.8,...,1.0}`, or, better, `{-1.0,-0.8,...,-0.2,0.0,0.2,...,1.0}` as in:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={30}{30},grid=major,
   /pgfplots/xtick={0,60,...,300},
   /pgfplots/ytick={0,60,...,300},
   /pgfplots/ztick={-1.0,-0.8,...,-0.2,0.0,0.2,...,1.0},
]
\addplot3[surf,domain=0:360,samples=40,
  colormap/jet,colorbar]
  {sin(x)*sin(y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I explicitly specified `...,-0.2,0.0,0.2,...` because otherwise, you might get a tick of 10^{-5} instead of 0.

[image: result]